# Loop in Thread is delayed how can I fix that

Tags: android, multithreading, loops

```
/**
* intervals of loop
*/
private final long HEART_BEAT_DELAY = 1000L;
private long lastTime = 0;
/**
* whether user is chatting with other(true:isChatting; false: not chatting)
*/
private boolean mIsChatting = false;
/**
* mainThread
*/
private Thread mThread = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    mThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);                 
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    //if user is chatting and activity is not finishing, keep cycling
    while (mIsChatting && !VideoChatViewActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
      try {
        sleep(HEART_BEAT_DELAY);
        //get current time
        long thisTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //get interval between current time and last request time
        long duration = thisTime - lastTime;
        //every 60 seconds do network request
        if (mIsChatting && duration >= 60 * 1000) {
          //set last heartbeat time to current time
          lastTime = thisTime;
          //network request
          mModel.sendHeartBeat(mUserId, mCallId);
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
};

        /**
         * start heartbeat thread
         */
        public void startHearBeat() {
            if (!mIsChatting) {
                mIsChatting = true;
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mThread.start();
            } else {
                LogUtil.e("ralph", "start second time, ignore it");
            }
        }

        /**
         * stop heartbeat thread
         */
        public void endHeartBeat() {
            mIsChatting = false;
        }
```

I've got this code and heartbeat should request network for every 60s, but sometimes it will wait to 90s to the next requet.
To fix that i've set processPriority and threadPriority,but they didn't work anyway.
How can i fix that make request on time?

Comment: If you are going to do timing in this way, you should take care to prevent your device from going to sleep. Make sure you have a foreground service and a `WakeLock`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are setting threadPriority to the highest, it means that you want this thread to run before anything else.
Try using `mThread.join()` in startHearBeat() method.

Comment: Wouldn't `join()`-ing it right after `start()`-ing it kinda make it... a synchronous function call?

Comment: @greeble31 That's what the intent is here, as per the question